# How to mock a method which passes in clazz?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method which has takes in a .class parameter.

For example:

```
ExampleService {
    def myExample(clazz){
        //do stuff and return some object
    }
}

/* How the above function gets used */
AnotherExampleService extends exampleService {


    def blah() {
        def obj = myExample(AnotherClass.class)
    }
}

/* Now I need to test the above blah() function */
AnotherExampleServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def "test blah"() {
        //The following doesn't seem to work
        ExampleService.metaClass.myExample = { def arg1 -> obj }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to Groovy/Grails, so any help would be much appreciated. I basically want to know why my unit test doesn't seem to work, and how to test such a function that takes in a paramter of a class instance.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably subclass the ExampleService in the test. So it looked like:

```
ExampleService {
    def myExample(clazz){
        //do stuff and return some object
    }
}

AnotherExampleService extends ExampleService {
    def exampleService

    def blah() {
        def obj = myExample(AnotherClass)
    }
}

AnotherExampleServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def "test blah"() {
        given:
           AnotherExampleService service = new AnotherExampleService() {
              @Override
              def myExample(clazz){
                 //whatever you want to do
                 return whatEverResult  
              }
        when:
           def result = service.blah (SomeClass)
        then: 
           result
    }
}
```

As you can see the myExample methods is overridden here to return some mock value and there's no tinkering with metaclass :-) To make it easier for Groovy you can explicitly state the input type e.g. `def myExample(Class clazz)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I made a mistake in my original post where I had exampleService as a field in AnotherExampleService, instead I had extended AnotherExampleService with exanpleService. How would I do it then?

Comment: Please update the question so it's clear what the problem is. Cheers!